# wordpress - custom page content in another page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I've found a couple of solutions to similar problems, but none of them does exactly what I want.

**→** I'm working with the Advanced Custom Fields(ACF) plugin to create custom field types. One of which is a gallery.

**→** I added the Polylang plugin to create two languages in my Wordpress.

**What I want**: I created a page where I setup the gallery. This content must be called in both the Dutch and English homepages.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how polylang works, but you can easily get content from any page by using ACF `<?php the_field('field', 111); ?>` where 111 is page ID.